# Jpa does not recognize WHERE condition

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables

```java
  class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    String name
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Book> books
    }
```

```java
class Book {
  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
        
    String name

    String time_stamp;
  
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Student student;    
}
```

So in the database, I have for example:

**Table Student**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

**Table Book**

| id | name | time_stamp | studentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bla | 12:00 | 1 |
| -- | ---- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 2 | Test | 12:45 | 1 |

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM student LEFT JOIN Book ON student.id = book.student.id WHERE book.time_stamp >= '12:00' AND book.time_stamp <= '12:00'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> findFromTo();
```

If we run the query in MySql Workbench everything is ok we receive only Students and books in given timestamp.

The problem occurs when we run the query through spring JPA here we receive Student between this timestamp but with all the books linked to the Student.

I want to receive in jpa Student object with Books objects which are filtered with timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to receive? You can LAZY fetch the books and customize the serialization.

If using Jackson you can customize the field you need for different views, look up the JsonView annotation.

You might also be interested in [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) on the repository side.

Comment: I want to receive the same result as in MySql Workbanch. Student with books in given timestamp not with all the books linked to the Student